# Can a sql table be used to generate a hash? [sqlserver2005]

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers, bulkinsert, last-modified

I'd like to take a table, generate it's hash string, store it, then compare it at a later predefined time and see if it matches, if not take note of the modification time and store that with the new change date.

This is because I believe an on insert trigger would cause a bad slow down if a batch of over 5000+ insert statements is submitted. I move large amounts of data per day and other than having a column of smalldatetime with a default get date, I have certain tables I do not have permissions to change the schema of, so I don't have a way to determine the last changed date of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CHECKSUM` on various fields to do this.